# How can i combine more than one getString into a textfield

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, getstring, scriptlet

i want to combine

```
rs.getString("PresentationDay")
rs.getString("PresentationStart")
rs.getString("PresentationEnd")
```

into one checkbox so these three will enter the database in one column.

this is my current code

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="availableTime" value="<%=rs.getString("PresentationDay")AND rs.getString("PresentationStart") AND rs.getString("PresentationEnd") %>">
```

but im getting error. How can i do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+` operator to concatenate the strings, e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="availableTime" value="<%=rs.getString("PresentationDay") + rs.getString("PresentationStart") + rs.getString("PresentationEnd") %>">
```